# Avoid Token validation Django RestFramework

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-rest-framework

I am using `Bearer token` in Django. I created a resource that must return some information if user is logged in and if user is not must return another information.

This is my Django Configuration

```py
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework_simplejwt.authentication.JWTAuthentication',
    )
}
```

If I send an expired token or an invalid one. It should return some information and 200 OK. But internally, Django returns 401 Unauthorized.

How can avoid that internal validation and call it whenever I want?

Comment: Create your own authentication class by inheriting `JWTAuthentication` class. In that class, raise [DRF API Exceptions](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/exceptions/#apiexception) with status code ***`2xx`***

Answer (score 0):

You want to allow any user/request to hit the endpoint, regardless of their permissions or authentication level, and then check manually.

To do this you just need to set your `permissions_classes` on the view/viewset properly so they won't get a 401/403.

The authentication classes (in `REST_FRAMEWORK` settings) will still run on each request and set the `request.user` object.

```
class MyApi(views.APIView):
    permission_classes=[AllowAny]  # clearer than just an empty list

    def get(self, request):
        if request.user and request.user.is_authenticated:
            return Response(data={"user": request.user.email})
        else:
            return Response(data={"user": "not logged in"})
```

You could also consult `request.user.is_anonymous`.  You don't strictly need to do the `request.user and` check since the user should always be present.  However, I have noticed that docs tools like swagger seem to skip the request pipline when generating the docs, so you may end up getting called *without* one sometimes.

Custom Authorization

I'm not familiar with SimpleJWT, but the pattern is the same with all auth classes.

1) Derive a new class from the base `JWTAuthenticatino` class
2) Overide whatever methosd you need
3) Set it as your default auth class in REST_FRAMEWORK

If you want to have the request go through anyway, then you never want to raise a 401 (ouch!).  In that case you'd just return None for the user, and set a custom attribute on the request that you can check later.  Remember, you have 2 cases: 1) bad / expired / etc token, and 2) no token passed, in which case your class won't be called

```
class MyAuth(JWTAuthentication):

    def authenticate(self, request):
        try: 
            orig = super().authenticate(request)
            if orig is None:
                 setattr(request, 'my_auth_failed', True)
            return orig
        except AuthenticationFailed as e:
             setattr(request, 'my_auth_failed, True)
             setattr(request, 'my_auth_error', e)

class MyView(APIView):
    authentication_classes = [MyAuth]
    permission_classes = [AllowAny]
```

I don't feel comfortable overriding the base authentication logic this way, but if its needed then go for it.  At least try to keep it as limited as possible and use it on as few views as you can.

Comment: It's still returning a 401 Unauthorized, I am testing sending a `Authorization: Bearer null` header

Comment: That may be because your header value of `null` is invalid, so it is raising a 401.  Try just not sending the Authorization header at all.

Comment: Thats what I want to solve. For example. If I send `Bearer valid_token_but_expired`, I want to get some information anyway

Comment: Oh, that makes some sense.  I don't know how the simple JWT lib works, the old one actually returns text in the detail of the error.  I'll add some more detail.